# Adding a slide view to images

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to get images from Internet. `(i can't show my code here)`. i AM storing a few images in a list and displaying them in an `imageview` each image after tapping other.

However, I want to make a slide of these images.

It's just a basic 'move to next picture' by `sliding your finger on the screen`.
Same as it would be in the phone photo gallery.
It's just to navigate through the images.

At the moment the image is going to the next one by the user tapping on the screen. But in this manner we can't go to the previous image. This is why we need to change the navigation to sliding a finger on the screen.

I have used `View Flipper` and `ViewPager` but how am i suppose to add images to these views after getting from internet each time.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here from below link you can download the example it can help you

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader